# Get the entry with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Hello I have this code :

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
margin = 0.23
entry = tk.entry(root).grid(row=1,column=1)

def profit_calculator():
    profit = margin*int(entry.get())
    print(profit)

button_calc = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=profit_calculator).grid(row=2,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to execute this code I put a value in the entry but when I clicked on the button I get this :

```
AttributeError : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have to use grid absolutely but I don't know why I get this error...

Can you help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: The code above doesn't raise the error you're claiming it does. It raises `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'entry'`. Which can be fixed by uppercasing the initial character of entry: `Entry(...`.

Answer (score 0):

`entry` right now is the return of `grid` which is always `None`. Separate the display call from widget object initiation. Replace:

```
entry = tk.entry(root).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

with:

```
entry = tk.Entry(root) # no predefined class named entry
entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
```